# Guidance for the probability of winning dice game?

Tags: probability

**Disclaimer: I am not looking for a solution to this, just a clue to help me arrive by myself to the right solution.**

> Two players are rolling a die, and the first one to get three ones,
>   wins. So far, player A has gotten two ones, and player B has gotten
>   one. What is the probability that player A wins?

What I am struggling with is the fact that the game can go on forever, so I am not sure of how to approach the problem. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard of a geometric random variable?

Comment: "The game will go on forever" should translate to an infinite geometric series in your solution.

Comment: I have not heard of it @Indefinite , and through the research I've been doing, it seems a geometric series is not strictly necessary?

Comment: Letting $P_A(a,b)$ (resp. $P_B(a,b)$) denote the probability that $A$ wins given that $A$ has thrown $a$ ones and $B$ has thrown $b$  given that it is $A's$ turn (resp. $B's$ turn), we get a simple backwards induction.

Comment: Note:  you did not specify whose turn it was.  That is clearly relevant.

Comment: I know, but our class instructor did not specify it either. I was thinking of solving it both ways just to make sure I am not missing anything @lulu

Comment: That sounds like a good strategy.  Do you understand what I mean about the backwards induction?

Comment: Not really @lulu, I think you mean that if it is A's turn, for instance, and A does not win, the situation would be reversed in between A and B for the next turn?

Comment: Well, that is part of it.  Suppose in your situation it is $A's$ turn.  Then, as you remark, looking at what happens next we see that $P_A(2,1)=\frac 16\times 1+\frac 56\times P_B(2,1)$.  Similarly $P_B(2,1)=\frac 16\times P_A(2,2)+\frac 56\times P_A(2,1)$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you @lulu, I will give it some more thought.

Comment: If you get stuck, send a comment to me and I will write some more.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier for you to cnsider 2 cases: 1) player 2 only tosses 0s before player 1 wins, 2) player 2 tosses one 1 before player 1 wins. Also for simplicity denote player 1 as A and player2 as B. Clearly the last step will be A. Since you did not specify who tossws first, i just assume it is A. So your possible outcomes are A, ABA, ABABA, etc to infinity. This is Geomerric series you can wasily compute, since p(a)=p(b)=0.5.

Can you handle the second case yourself? Since they are mutually exclusive, jyst sum the outcomes.